# How can i increase the number of digits after the dot?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that calculates the cubic root of any number

```
cube = int(input("Please Enter the number : "))
root = 0.0
tries = 0
add = 1
positive = True


while root ** 3 < cube or root ** 3 > cube :
    if root ** 3 < cube :
        if positive == True :
            root += add
            tries += 1
        elif positive == False :
            positive = True
            add = add/10
            tries += 1
    elif root ** 3 > cube :
        if positive == True :
            positive = False
            add = add/10
            tries += 1
        elif positive == False :
            root -= add
            tries += 1

print("The root is " + str(root) + ", Tries : " + str(tries))
```

when I go to http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html and try to debug the code I see that if I assign the value 11 to 'cube' for example, (in step 227) and when I decide 'add' (which is 0.0001) by 10 it becomes 0. why ??!!

Comment: Well, you are doing 'add = add/10' each time, and I'm pretty sure that's not what you mean. Also, comparing floating point numbers for equality is not a great idea.

Comment: No, it's not each time. I'm doing  'add = add/10' only when 2 cases happen
Whatever, How the code should be like?

Comment: I think `add = add/2` might work-- you can shrink down the stepsize by 50% each time, but not by 90%

Comment: It doesn't work, Gives an infinite loop and as before, after some steps add becomes 0.

Comment: To be honest, this is just plain ugly code. What you're trying to do is a binary search and this is not the way to code it.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you tell me the correct way to write this code? (can you give me the right code)